# How to measure how much download quota used when web page loaded?

Tags: python, selenium, curl, rselenium, netstat

I am attempting to quantify how much download quota would be consumed when a certain web page is loaded (in chrome  in my case), including all the page's assets (e.g. 'loaded' according to regular human use of the webpage)

Is there a way to achieve this using mainstream techniques (e.g. a python library, selenium, netstat command line utility, curl or something else)?

Note: I guess one *very* crude way would be to check my ISP stats before/after the page load, but this is fraught with potential inaccuracies, probably most notably the device doing background tasks and the ISP not providing quota estimates fine enough to discern the additional kbs consumed by the page load, so I think this method would not be reliable

Answer (score 1):

There may be better ways, but I found one that seems to work

In chrome, open developer tools (cmd + option + j), click on the 'network' tab, and refresh the page. When it has fully loaded, look for the resources.

Note: to get an accurate reading, it could be important to ensure the 'Disable cache' checkbox is ticked (failing to disallow the cache could underestimate the download quota required)

For the [page we're on now](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/62529970/how-to-measure-how-much-download-quota-used-when-web-page-loaded), we see it uses 1.5MB without disabling the cache.

[image]

Note: the amount seemed to vary for me quite a bit each time I ran it (not always in a downward direction), so depending on the circumstances, it could be worth doing this several times and taking an average.